# Can't activate I2C on my B+

Tags: raspbian, i2c

I'm trying to use the I2C pins on my Pi.
All guides I can find talks about that I have to activate it using ether /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf or raspi-config. However, nether works, the file doesn't exists and raspi-config returns "command not found"

I'm using a B+ modle running raspbian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume this is a new install.

That being the case you will be using the device tree feature of the latest Linux kernels.

Edit /boot/config.txt and add the following line

```
dtparam=i2c1=on
```

Add the following lines to /etc/modules

```
i2c-dev
i2c-bcm2708
```

Get the following package

```
sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
```

Reboot.

After reboot the device /dev/i2c-1 should be present.

```
i2cdetect -y 1
```

will show connected devices.

---

**EDITED TO ADD**

Note, the advice I give here to use i2c1 is officially deprecated.  See /boot/overlays/README on the Pi for the reason that i2c_arm is now preferred.

Comment: @joan: Being interested in this answer too, I looked into the config.txt content of my Rpi (model B with recent raspbian distro, running kernel 3.18.7) and I see "dtparam=i2c_arm=on" instead.  Is this similar to your solution?  What's the difference, if any?

Comment: @GeertVc Sometimes the people who implement these things think they are being helpful.  I'm not convinced they are always right.  i2c_arm and i2c_arm_baudrate are synonyms for i2c1 and i2c1_baudrate.  The current recommendation is to use the i2c_arm variant.  See /boot/overlays/README for an explanation.  I'll edit my answer to include a link to that file.

Comment: Clear.  Perfect!

Comment: You are correct that i2cd is no longer valid.  But I am noticing that some of my Rpi3 machines have a problem with i2cdetect -y 1 and throw a bunch of errors.  Just using i2cdetect 1 (then answering y to the question) solves the problem.  I have never had to edit those modules entries on my Rpi3..

Comment: By the way, @Joan, I wish there was a direct way to interact with you.  For instance, on the Arduino side, I wonder if you have observed that a loop reading voltages (to pass on to the Pi), and running the Serial Plotter, you can see serious disruptions in the readings caused my moving the mouse.  This is why I am so glad the Arduino can be the one to choose when to send.  Another quick question:  What is an Rpi3's default I2C address?

Comment: @SDsolar There is no default address.  The Pi doesn't act as a slave until you configure it, and when you configure it you specify the slave address.

Comment: Thank you, @Joan.   Another question:  Can the Rpi3 be configured to monitor the i2C bus and show all the traffic between other devices?

Comment: @SDsolar I'm not aware of one.  Obviously the kernel driver could do this trivially.  http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_I2C_sniffer will let you sniff slow traffic.  If you use it I suggest you start the daemon with `sudo pigpiod -s2` to increase the sampling rate.